# how to use pdf and mfrow in R

Tags: r, pdf

I would like to create a 1 page pdf document which contains 5 graphs. I would like the 1st graph to be the main graph, taking up about a 1/3 of the page. Whilst the last 4 other graphs be of the same size.

So far I am using:

```
pdf('Austriacus fish2, obs1,FG')
par(mfrow=c(3,2))
plot(c.aus3.1FG$x.position,c.aus2.1FG$y.position)
plot(c.aus3.1FG$x.position,type="o")
plot(c.aus3.1FG$y.position, type="o")
acf(x.tsc.aus3.1FG,100)
acf(y.tsc.aus3.1FG,100)
dev.off()
```

But this is creating 3 rows with 2 graphs each.

The main graph needs to be:

```
plot(c.aus1.1FG$x.position,c.aus1.1FG$y.position)
```

And the 4 smaller graphs need to be:

```
plot(c.aus3.1FG$x.position,type="o")
    plot(c.aus3.1FG$y.position, type="o")
    acf(x.tsc.aus3.1FG,100)
    acf(y.tsc.aus3.1FG,100)
```

Comment: Try `layout` to customize the sizes and positions of your sub-figures?

Comment: As xb said, mfrow will only do evenly spaced grids. `layout` is what you want.

Comment: Some examples, [Combining Plots](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is `layout()`. For example:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,
                2,3,
                4,5), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
for (i in seq_len(5)) {
plot(1:10)
}
layout(1)
```

[image]

Read `?layout` for more details as you can control the heights of the panels etc.